# GRASS GIS not importing any Shp File - UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: grass-7.0, encode

I tried to work on a project to get isochrones with GRASS Tools. I keep getting error messages in QGIS so I tried using GRASS as a standalone but I get the following error message when I try to import any layer from any project I have on my Harddisk:

*UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)*

The only thing that is changing it the position number in this error message. What is going on? My shapes are in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use v.in.org command in GRASS. The input dialog has two tabs Source settings and Import settings. Change to the Import settings and fill the encoding (probably UTF-8).

[image]